# Supremum of a polynomial over reals

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ be a quadratic form, where a,b,c are real numbers. Find the supremum of $p(x)$ over $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a>0;$ $\sup(p(x))\rightarrow\infty$.

If $a<0$ $\sup(p(x))=p(-b/2a)$